# Show / Hide images randomly using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a function that grabs all the instances of an image class on the page. As default these will be hidden, then randomly after a certain interval show one of those images (can be any image). Then the function will rerun and show another image. (whilst hiding the image that was shown on the first run through.

I've got to this stage with the function (not currently working)

```
(function randomShow() {
var showDiv = $('.show'),
    el = showDiv.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * showDiv.length));        
    el.show().delay(2000).show(randomShow);   
})();
```

Thanks

Comment: what is `fadeDivs` and `showFade`? Try to provide a more complete exmaple.

Comment: My apologies, I've edited the variable names. This is just an example to see if I'm on the right lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a jsFiddle using divs in place of images to demonstrate (pure js):

http://jsfiddle.net/oogley_boogley/az9gd8wf/

the script:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('square');
var arrLength = divs.length;
var randomNumberLimit;
var interval_speed = 1000;

setInterval(function(){
randomNumberLimit = Math.floor((Math.random() * arrLength) + 1);
for(i=0;i<arrLength;i++){
    var matchingDiv = divs[i];
    if(matchingDiv.id == randomNumberLimit){
        matchingDiv.setAttribute("class","showing square blue");
    }
    if(matchingDiv.id != randomNumberLimit){
        matchingDiv.setAttribute("class","hiding square blue");
    }
}
}, interval_speed);
```